# music widget in page template - select options

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, widget, instance

I am using the Rockit Now wordpress theme, which comes with a music player widget. When adding the widget to a sidebar, you have the followings options- 
Title- (a section to type text..)
Artist for playlist- (a dropdown menu with all artist post names)
No of tracks to play- (a section to type a number..)

I am trying to display this widget in my artist page template so that it appears on each artist page with the music for that particular artist post.

I have added the following to my single-artists.php page template-

```
 <?php the_widget( 'cs_music_player' ); ?>
```

This has successfully called the widget as I am now receiving the message 'No Results Found' on the page.. What I need to do is be able to select the options as above in the php.. I unfortunately can't work out how to do this..

Here is the cs_music_playlist_widget.php code-

```
<?php
class cs_music_player extends WP_Widget
{
  function cs_music_player()
  {
    $widget_ops = array('classname' => 'cs_music_player', 'description' => 'Select artist to Play Your Playlist.' );
    $this->WP_Widget('cs_music_player', 'ChimpS : MusicPlayList', $widget_ops);
  }

  function form($instance)
  {
    $instance = wp_parse_args( (array) $instance, array( 'title' => '' ) );
    $title = $instance['title'];
    $get_post_slug = isset( $instance['get_post_slug'] ) ? esc_attr( $instance['get_post_slug'] ) : '';
    $numtrack = isset( $instance['numtrack'] ) ? esc_attr( $instance['numtrack'] ) : '';

?>
    <p>
      <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>">
          <span>Title: </span>
          <input class="upcoming" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>" size="40" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('title'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr($title); ?>" />
      </label>
    </p>
    <br />

    <p>
      <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('get_post_slug'); ?>">
          <span>artist for Playlist:</span>
          <br /><br />

          <select name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('get_post_slug'); ?>" style="width:225px;">
          <?php
                global $wpdb,$post;
                $args = array( 'post_type' => 'artists', 'posts_per_page' => -1,'post_status'=> 'publish');
                $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
                while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
            ?>  
                    <option <?php if($get_post_slug == $post->post_name){echo 'selected';}?> value="<?php echo $post->post_name;?>">
                    <?php echo substr(get_the_title(), 0, 20);  if ( strlen(get_the_title()) > 20 ) echo "...";?>
                    </option>
                <?php endwhile;  ?>
          </select>
      </label>
    </p>

    <p>
      <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('noot'); ?>">
          <span>No Of Tracks To Play: </span>
          <input class="upcoming" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('numtrack'); ?>" size="2" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('numtrack'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr($numtrack); ?>" />
      </label>
    </p>
    <div class="clear"></div>
<?php
  }

  function update($new_instance, $old_instance)
  {
    $instance = $old_instance;
    $instance['title'] = $new_instance['title'];
    $instance['get_post_slug'] = $new_instance['get_post_slug'];
    $instance['numtrack'] = $new_instance['numtrack'];  
    return $instance;
  }

    function widget($args, $instance)
    {
        global $cs_transwitch;
        extract($args, EXTR_SKIP);
        $title = empty($instance['title']) ? ' ' : apply_filters('widget_title', $instance['title']);
        $get_post_slug = empty($instance['get_post_slug']) ? ' ' : apply_filters('widget_title', $instance['get_post_slug']);       
         echo $before_widget;
         $args=array(
          'name' => $get_post_slug,
          'post_type' => 'artists',
          'post_status' => 'publish',
          'showposts' => 1,
        );
        $get_posts = get_posts($args);
        if( $get_posts ) {
            $get_post_id = $get_posts[0]->ID;
        }else{
            $get_post_id = '';
        }

        // WIDGET display CODE Start
        if (!empty($title))

            echo $before_title . $title . $after_title;
            global $wpdb;
            if($get_post_id <> ""){
             $artist_buy_amazon_db ='';
             $artist_buy_apple_db = '';
             $artist_buy_groov_db ='';
             $artist_buy_cloud_db = '';          
             $cs_artist = get_post_meta($get_post_id, "cs_artist", true);
                 if ( $cs_artist <> "" ) {
                     $xmlObject = new SimpleXMLElement($cs_artist);
                         $artist_release_date_db = $xmlObject->artist_release_date;
                         $artist_buy_amazon_db = $xmlObject->artist_buy_amazon;
                         $artist_buy_apple_db = $xmlObject->artist_buy_apple;
                         $artist_buy_groov_db = $xmlObject->artist_buy_groov;
                         $artist_buy_cloud_db = $xmlObject->artist_buy_cloud;
                        enqueue_alubmtrack_format_resources('widget');
                        ?>
                         <script>
                        jQuery(document).ready(function($){
                            new jPlayerPlaylist({
                                jPlayer: "#jquery_jplayer_<?php echo $get_post_id;?>",
                                cssSelectorAncestor: "#jp_container_<?php echo $get_post_id;?>"
                            }, [                                         
                                 <?php  
                                     $my_counter = 0;
                                     foreach ( $xmlObject as $track ){
                                         if ( $track->getName() == "track" ) {
                                             if ( $my_counter < $instance['numtrack'] ) {
                                                 $artist_track_title = $track->artist_track_title;
                                                 $artist_track_mp3_url = $track->artist_track_mp3_url;
                                                 echo '{';
                                                 echo 'title:"'.$artist_track_title.'",';
                                                 echo 'mp3:"'.$artist_track_mp3_url.'"';
                                                 echo '},';
                                             }
                                             $my_counter++;
                                         }
                                     }
                        ?>
                            ], {
                                swfPath: "<?php echo get_template_directory_uri()?>/scripts/frontend/Jplayer.swf",
                                supplied: "mp3",
                                wmode: "window"
                            });
                        });                                                     
                        </script>                                         

                        <!-- Now Playing Start -->
                        <div class="nowplaying">
                            <?php $cs_by = __('By: %s', CSDOMAIN); ?>
                            <h5><a href="<?php echo get_permalink($get_post_id); ?>"><?php if($get_post_id <> ''){echo get_the_title($get_post_id);}?></a></h5>
                            <p><a href="<?php echo get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) ); ?>"><?php printf($cs_by, get_the_author()); ?></a> - <?php if(isset($artist_release_date_db)){ if($cs_transwitch =='on'){ _e('Release Date',CSDOMAIN); }else{ echo __CS('release_date', 'Release Date'). ' : '.$artist_release_date_db; }}?></p>
                            <div id="jquery_jplayer_<?php echo $get_post_id;?>" class="jp-jplayer"></div>
                            <div id="jp_container_<?php echo $get_post_id;?>" class="jp-audio">
                                <div class="jp-type-playlist">
                                    <div class="jp-gui jp-interface">
                                        <ul class="jp-controls">
                                            <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-previous" tabindex="1">previous</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-play" tabindex="1">play</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-pause" tabindex="1">pause</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-next" tabindex="1">next</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-stop" tabindex="1">stop</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-mute" tabindex="1" title="mute">mute</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-unmute" tabindex="1" title="unmute">unmute</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-volume-max" tabindex="1" title="max volume">max volume</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                        <div class="jp-progress">
                                            <div class="jp-seek-bar">
                                                <div class="jp-play-bar"></div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="jp-volume-bar">
                                            <div class="jp-volume-bar-value"></div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="jp-current-time"></div>
                                        <div class="jp-duration"></div>
                                        <ul class="jp-toggles">
                                            <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-shuffle" tabindex="1" title="shuffle">Shuffle</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-shuffle-off" tabindex="1" title="shuffle off">Shuffle off</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-repeat" tabindex="1" title="repeat">Repeat All</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-repeat-off" tabindex="1" title="repeat off">Repeat off</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="jp-playlist">
                                        <ul>
                                            <li></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <?php if($artist_buy_amazon_db <> '' or $artist_buy_apple_db <> '' or $artist_buy_groov_db <> '' or $artist_buy_cloud_db <> ''){?>
                        <!-- Buy Now Start -->
                        <div class="buynow">
                            <h5 class="white"><?php if($cs_transwitch =='on'){ _e('BUY NOW',CSDOMAIN); }else{ echo __CS('buy_now', 'BUY NOW'); } ?></h5>
                            <ul>
                                <?php if($xmlObject->artist_buy_cloud <> ""){?><li><a href="<?php echo $xmlObject->artist_buy_cloud;?>" class="soundcloud">&nbsp;</a></li><?php }?>
                                <?php if($xmlObject->artist_buy_amazon <> ""){?><li><a href="<?php echo $xmlObject->artist_buy_amazon;?>" class="amazon">&nbsp;</a></li><?php }?>
                                <?php if($xmlObject->artist_buy_apple <> ""){?><li><a href="<?php echo $xmlObject->artist_buy_apple;?>" class="apple">&nbsp;</a></li><?php }?>
                                <?php if($xmlObject->artist_buy_groov <> ""){?><li><a href="<?php echo $xmlObject->artist_buy_groov;?>" class="grooveshark">&nbsp;</a></li><?php }?>
                            </ul>
                            <!-- Buy Now End -->
                            <div class="clear"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                        <?php } //Buy now Condition end?>
                      <?php }else{?>
                        <div class="list-thumb">
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <h2><?php _e("No results found.",CSDOMAIN); ?></h2>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                          <?php
                          } 
        } // if artist is not Selected 
        else{
             echo '<div class="box-small no-results-found"> <h5>';
                _e("No results found.",CSDOMAIN);
            echo ' </h5></div>';

            }
    echo $after_widget;
    }
}

add_action( 'widgets_init', create_function('', 'return register_widget("cs_music_player");') );?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`the_widget`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_widget) accept three arguments:

- `$widget` : the widget name, in your case `cs_music_player`
- `$instance` : the widget instance settings. It's an array where your widget options goes. You can do something like this: `array('title' => 'Your widget title', 'get_post_slug' => 'slug_of_your_artist', 'numtrack' => 10)`
- `$args` : an array of options used to display your widget. You can send an empty array to use the defaults, or just ignore that parameter.

In the end, your widget call will look like that:

```
global $post;
the_widget(
    'cs_music_player',
    array(
        'title' => 'Your widget title',
        'get_post_slug' => $post->post_name,
        'numtrack' => 10
    )
);
```

Comment: thanks @vard :) that's working! One more question.. how can I call the post_slug automatically for the particular page that's showing so the relevant music plays for each different post?

Comment: I've worked it out! :) I changed the code to <?php the_widget( 'cs_music_player', array('title' => 'Music', 'get_post_slug' => the_slug() , 'numtrack' => '10' ) ); ?> and added this to functions.php /** Admin Slug Function */
function the_slug() {
    $post_data = get_post($post->ID, ARRAY_A);
    $slug = $post_data['post_name'];
    return $slug;
}

Comment: Nice you get it worked :) I updated the question with an other way to get the slug, withoud adding a function - through the global `$post` object you can get the slug of the current post without having to query anything.